# How to cite "Of contraseñas, תואמסיס, and 密码" for ACM TAPS submission?

Tags: hebrew, acmart, chinese

I've managed to cite this paper using the packages `CJKutf8` and `cjhebrew` and the following bibtex entry:

```
@inproceedings{bonneau2012contrasenas,
  title={Of contrase{\~n}as, \cjRL{sysm'wt}, and \begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}密码\end{CJK*}--Character encoding issues for web passwords},
  author={Bonneau, Joseph and Xu, Rubin},
  year={2012},
  booktitle={Web 2.0 Security and Privacy},
  publisher={IEEE}
}
```

Is there a way to cite this paper in a form suitable for submission to the ACM TAPS system, which [only allows certain packages](https://authors.acm.org/proceedings/production-information/accepted-latex-packages)?

Comment: Create standalone PDF/image files for the two words, then `\includegraphics` them with `graphicx` package into your main document.

Comment: The `lccode` character trick needs suitable fonts, which ACM may, or may not, have or allow.

Comment: `\documentclass{standalone} \usepackage{cjhebrew} \begin{document} \cjRL{sysm'wt}\end{document}` and `\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{fontspec} \setmainfont{FandolSong} \begin{document} 密码 \end{document}`. Compile with lualatex. Use whichever fonts are suitable.

Comment: Ask ACM how they want to process such matters. It may be that Unicode characters are outside or beyond their legacy toolchain's ability. A fallback would be to use transliterated versions of the words.

Answer (score 1):

The author replied to an email inquiry with the suggestion to flatten the characters as follows:

```
@inproceedings{BX12,
        url="https://www.jbonneau.com/doc/BX12-W2SP-passwords_character_encoding.pdf",
        author="Joseph Bonneau and Rubin Xu",
        title="{Of contrase{\~{n}}as, sysmawt, and m\`{i}m\v{a}: Character encoding issues for web passwords}",
        location="San Francisco, CA, USA",
        booktitle="Web 2.0 Security {\&} Privacy",
        year="2012",
        month="May",
}
```

This produces "Joseph Bonneau and Rubin Xu. 2012. Of contraseñas, sysmawt, and mìmˇa: Character encoding issues for web passwords. In Web 2.0 Security & Privacy (San
Francisco, CA, USA). [https://www.jbonneau.com/doc/BX12-W2SP-passwords_character_encoding.pdf"](https://www.jbonneau.com/doc/BX12-W2SP-passwords_character_encoding.pdf%22). While this is not searchable (the unicode version is), fortunately the included link to the paper is valid. Ultimately it should provide enough information for an interested reader to track down the citation (which makes the point that it's difficult to reliably use non-ASCII characters in passwords, then deliberately uses a bunch in the title).